# Error instantiating bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: grails-orm, grails3, micronaut

I am writing a small APP using micronaut and gorm. The APP contains two domains, Book and Author.

```
    package micronaut.query.association.domain
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference
    import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity

    @grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
    class Author implements GormEntity<Author> {
        String name
    @JsonManagedReference
        List<Book> books

        static mapping = {
        books fetch: 'join'
        }
    }
    package micronaut.query.association.domain

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference
    import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity

    @grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
    class Book implements GormEntity<Book> {
        String name
    @JsonBackReference
    Author authorx
    }
}
```

The APP compiles without problems but when I run the APP I receive the following error:

11:50:08.697 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Repeated column in mapping for entity: micronaut.query.association.domain.Book column: authorx_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

If in the Author class I change the line "List books" to "Set books", the APP runs without problems.

Also if I use Collection instead of List the APP runs correctly.

I can reproduce the same situation using grails 3.3.9.

Comment: Try adding `static belongsTo = [authorx: Author]` to the book class

Comment: I tried to add "static belongsTo = [authorx: Author] to the book class" as suggested by james-kleeh, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message you provided may be miss-leading you a bit. Grails, more so hibernate, want you to use a [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for the associations.

Comment: Grails supports List

Comment: If I use Collection instead of List, the APP compiles and executes correctly.